# Anyone find the reset tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have 88 questions tagged [reset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/reset). It's used for almost any kind of reset action, from reset preferences to reset the system. I don't find that tag useful at all. Someone has been suggesting a tag wiki, but whenever I check the questions that are currently tagged (and as answerer) I see no pattern other than resetting stuff. I find more useful that the question is tagged with the thing you want to "reset" instead of a tag to "reset" anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [reset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/reset) is just a hodge-podge of questions that in some way need something "reset".  I don't think it serves a purpose here because there are much better, more specific tags for most if not all of the questions in that tag.